Is there a way to get the web app domain in Main() (program.cs)?
When my application starts I want to have it create the sitemap.txt dynamically. Doing so requires I have the domain of the website which differs for the dev and production slots.
Is there a way to get this in Main()? I think logically that should be known by the system. But Blazor only has NavigationManager and that service appears to only be available in the context of a page.
If not, I can stuff the value into a singleton service when the first page loads and then have a BackgroundService create the files. Asking here to avoid all that.
Update: The specification for a sitemap.txt is here (along with the spec for sitemap.xml).

Is this a similar question to yours? If so, the comments may be helpful.

@devlincarnate Those comments make me think this may not be possible.

"Is there a way to get this in Main()?" - In short, no - because Main can be configured to run before any HTTP request has been received.

"I think logically that should be known by the system" - On the contrary: the system has no way of knowing what your HTTP bindings are (and bindings can change at runtime too).

How do you plan to handle subsequent incoming requests with a Host: header that differs from the first request?

I do these as Build Tasks and generate the files the application needs. This also separates the concern - the app handles incoming requests for users and the build generates the static sitemap.xml file for crawlers. Alternatively if it must be dynamic on-the-fly you can make the sitemap.xml a route with an [AllowAnonymous] and hook it up
via routes.MapRoute(name: "Sitemap",url: "sitemap.xml" and cache the result.

@Dai I hadn't thought of the Host: issue. Do I need to do a different sitemap.txt for each? I can do as @JeremyThompson suggests and have a Controller for it (yes cached) if I need to do that.

@DavidThielen I'll admit that I don't know what sitemap.txt is - the old Site Maps XML feature from (non-Core) ASP.NET was last documented in 2014 and doesn't seem relevant to ASP.NET Core.

@JeremyThompson at present I am creating a physical file in the root folder. If there's a change that will add/remove a file (happens 10 - 20 times/day) I set a flag and then in the background service (runs every 5 minutes), it regenerates the physical file. Is this the best way to handle this? Regenerating takes well under a second.

@DavidThielen Why write anything to disk? Why can't you keep it in-memory?

@Dai sitemap.txt is like sitemap.xml but it's just a url per line. The Google crawler supports it and it's identical to a sitemap.xml without the last update datetime element for each file.

@Dai I can keep it in memory, but why?

@DavidThielen In secure production environments, it's best to completely disallow any web-application from writing to any public/web-accessible directory, because that's how  you get hacked (e.g. saving an uploaded l33tshell.php file). Granted, you could save the text file to a non-accessible directory and use a Controller Action to read and return the file via FileResult (for example).

@Dai good point. If you write this all up as an answer, happy to select it.

Looks like you two have it sorted.

@DavidThielen I'm currently in a call right now - I'll be able to write it up probably within an hour.

@Dai thank you - your answers are always great. And I'm guessing others will hit this same question. The multiple 'Hosts:' was a really good point too as my app accepts company.domain.com where the company is the name of different organizations and it then returns a subset of pages to match. So they each need a sitemap.txt and robots.txt. This discussion was very helpful.

"your answers are always great" - selection-bias: it's only because the mean ol' moderators delete my memetastic shitposts

Does your web-application run as multiple instances? either in a single-machine-multiple-w3wp scenario (aka "web garden") or on multiple distinct machines/VMs (e.g. Azure AppServices multiple instances) - with-or-without shared storage?

@Dai I have it scaled out to 2 instances on Azure App Server.

The server itself doesn't know about it's domain name, as it's only ever accessed by it's IP. The reason you can see the domain name during a request is because it is sent with the request, or, in the frontend, because the browser knows it.
You could look at builder.Environment and load the domain name for the current environment from a configuration file.
You could also make the sitemap.txt point to a controller and generate it every time it's requested, but depending on the size of your website this may take too long. This has the pro that it doesn't need to write to your filesystem.
